# Why is the book still wanted if Aida has memorized it?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

In Season 4 of *Agents of SHIELD*, it was shown that android 'has memorized the complete Darkhold'<sup>[source](http://murcray.blogspot.co.uk/2016/11/agents-of-shield-theories-deals-with.html)</sup> (E07), so why does her creator still want a book so badly (E09)?

He could use Aida to create a new high-tech technology based on her knowledge and understanding (as she already did it), or ask her to dump the remembered content back into readable format. Secondly, even if he manage to get a book, he wouldn't understand it anyway, so why the struggle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll have to re-watch the episodes to make sure, but as far as I remember her creator didn't have much private access to Aida after her reading the Darkhold. So we can probably assume he never managed to make a copy of the data. After Aida was stopped her head (which seems to be where her data storage is) was held by SHIELD so we can assume he was unable to access her data after this point.

So while Aida has the full Darkhold in her data storage (provided nothing was corrupted or damaged by chopping her head off) her creator has no way to access this data. Additionally he probably assumes her head was destroyed or wiped once it was taken by SHIELD. So his only remaining option is to get access to the book itself.

On top of this the Darkhold presents itself in a data format that its reader can understand, in Aida's case it was binary numbers. But once Aida had recorded the data it was just data. For example if a Spanish-speaking character tried to copy the contents onto some other paper then that copy won't magically translate itself for English-speaking characters. Aida's copy would need to be translated into English for it to be of any use and this would be incredibly hard, the binary numbers probably don't just represent text as computers don't directly work on text. The data that Aida saw was probably in the form of machine instructions which translate into commands such as ADD, STORE, COPY etc. While these easily "translate" to English it would not make any sense, computer "language" is just too abstract for us to understand like that.

Comment: Last paragraph is plausible. But first two do not make sense. Aida's head was chopped off when she was trying to retrieve the DARKHOLD.

Answer (score 7):

We don't know if AIDA has read the whole book, we certainly don't see her *finish* it nor is their dialogue to that effect...

...even your source is clear on that.

> **We have no idea if she read the whole book or just some of it**, but SHE knows way more than she needed to bring people back.

Certainly, she could download what she *has* but there's no indication that she  could translate it into something understandable by humans....she sees binary code.

> Secondly, even if he managed to get the book, he wouldn't understand it anyway, so why the struggle?

Yes, he would. The book is a **mystical** object.

The Darkhold **wants** to be understood and makes itself readable.

This is how it looks to AIDA

[image]

...and this is how it looks to humans

[image]

There's dialogue in S4 Episode 5 that the readers of the book see it as written in their **native language**.

> "I didn't think it would be in German."
>
> "No I'm reading English. Wait, are you not seeing what I'm seeing?"